# How get MAX(id) for each username?

Tags: mysql

I have this MySQL table:

[image]

How get maximum id for each username?

Like above in the image, I desire just to get the rows with username 'mostafa' OR 'samsung' but with max id.

I testing a lot of query, like :

```
SELECT MAX(id) , latitude, longitude FROM 'users_geo' WHERE username = 'mostafa'
```

This just returns record with max id for username mostafa.

Also test this query:

```
SELECT id, latitude, longitude FROM `users_geo` WHERE username = 'samsung' HAVING MAX( id ) LIMIT 0 , 30
```

This query just return wrong result. query return row with `id=9` while max id for user 'samsung' is `21`.

Comment: instead of an image of the table please set up a sqlfiddle so we can reproduce the issue.

Comment: See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html

Comment: @Lelio Faieta: Thanks..for mention, i am not familiar with [SQlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/). but this is  pastebin (http://pastebin.com/Pz6CP3mE)

Answer (score 0):

Use `mysql` [group by](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) with a [Aggregate (GROUP BY) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html) namely `max` in your case.

```
select username, max(id) from users_geo group by username;
```

Comment: Thanks. I use this --> `SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM `users_geo` ORDER BY `id` DESC) tmp GROUP BY tmp.`username`; ` , but return error :  `#1248 - Every derived table must have its own alias`

Comment: `group by` should be used with a [Aggregate (GROUP BY) Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). Try this `SELECT tmp.usename, max(tmp.id) FROM (SELECT * FROM users_geo ORDER BY id DESC) tmp GROUP BY tmp.username;` or briefly  `select username, max(id) from users_geo group by username;`

Comment: Thanks...using this [link](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/47e5f024a08b3f6c6302)  and worked.